# Can't represent a size of 2147483645 in Constraints

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max),horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        val modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = modifier,
            value = user.userName, 
            onValueChange = {
                
            },
            singleLine = true
        )
        
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(text = "登录")
        }
     
    }
```

I want the Button width to be the same as the OutlinedTextField width,so I user `IntrinsicSize.Max`,but I encountered a fatal error.How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When I try running your example, it works just fine and does not crash for me.
Nonetheless, I think you meant to use `IntrinsicSize.Min`, which will make your `Button` fill the entire width but not be wider than the `OutlinedTextField`.

You can read more on how to use Intrinsic measurements here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements